# How to create a script that will build an apk from sources with xml string resource as parameter?

Tags: android, xml, bash, makefile, build

I am working on kind of deploy script to compile APK for different app ids that could be run by non-android developers.

Let's say that I have an app Android Studio project with all sources and libraries within it, and now I need to compile this project 3 times for 3 different development facebook apps. This requires building app 3 times, each with different facebook app id (the app id is stored in XML resources).

For now, the app id is hardcoded within XML string resources but this is inconvenient for non-developers as they don't know how to rebuild the project.

The expected solution would be a script that works like:

```
compile.sh <project_path> <fb_app_id>
```

Which creates an APK file with FB app ID stored in XML string resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may inject resources with gradle 
write at your defaultConfig section `resValue "string", "{resource id}", "\"$FB_APP_ID\""` and build with gradle. You should run gradle with -PFB_APP_ID="{your app id}" eg `./gradlew assembleDebug -PFB_APP_ID="10"`

Comment: Got it with
resValue "string", "welcomeTextMessage", findProperty("WELCOME_TEXT_MESSAGE")
Seems more clear to me. Thank you